# RCA Galileo Pro Upgrade?

Tags: updates, external-sd, internal-sd

I have the RCA Galileo Pro and it is very slow, is there a way to upgrade?  I have always had a Samsung, so this is a big change.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. you gave less information so we don't know if upgrade is possible or you are already on recent version. consider factory reset it will fix most problems (all personal data will be erased)

Comment: For starters: have you seen our [updates tag wiki](/tags/updates/info)? Further, as alecxs already pointed out, some more details would be helpful – like the Android version you're on, the manufacturer, possibly a link to the specs. Apart from that, an upgrade won't necessarily make it faster – a "cleanup" (like the factory reset) on the other hand usually does.

Comment: I assume it's [RCA Galileo Pro 2-in-1 Android tablet](https://www.rca.com/us_en/tablets-25-us-en/android-2-in-1-365-us-en/11-galileo-pro-11-5-android-2-in-1-195-us-en)? From the hardware specs, looks like it's inferior compared to even [Samsung Galaxy S6](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s6-6849.php). So, I'm not sure if what you're looking for is a hardware upgrade or software upgrade.

Comment: Sorry, it is a RCA Galileo Pro 11.5" 32GB 2-in-1 Android 8.1.

Comment: I did just reinstall and it also did a system update.  That was the first one since I purchased.